# Replace NaN values in entire dataframe with average of others

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I have several DataFrames (DataFrames have the same index and column structure). The problem is that there are NaN values in these dataframes.

I want to replace these NaN values by mean value of other's DataFrames' corresponding values.

For exapmle let's look at 3 dataframes.

DataFrame1 with `1:M2` NaN :

```
   M1   M2    M3        
0  1    1     2  
1  8   NaN    9 
2  4    2     7       
3  9    6     3
```

DataFrame 2 with NaN value at `0:M3`:

```
   M1   M2    M3        
0  2    3    NaN  
1  1    1     6 
2  1    2     9       
3  4    6     2
```

DataFrame3:

```
   M1   M2    M3        
0  1    4     2  
1  2    9     1 
2  1    6     5       
3  1    NaN     4
```

So we replace NaN in first DataFrame by 5 `(9+1)/2`. Second NaN should be replaced by 2 because `(2+2)/2`, third by 6 and so on.

Is there any good and elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way using `numpy.nanmean`.

```
avg = np.nanmean([df1.values, df2.values, df3.values], axis=0)

for df in [df1, df2, df3]:
    df[df.isnull()] = avg
    df = df.astype(int)
```

Note: since `np.nan` is `float`, we convert explicitly back to `int`.

Comment: It works with the data you provided.. Not sure what's in your dataframes. I assume `NaN` in your dataframe is `np.nan`, not a string. I would check `df.dtypes` for each dataframe.

Comment: Give `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly` error at `avg = np.nanmean([df1.values, df2.values, df3.values], axis=0)`

Comment: they are objects

Comment: @DavidLihtalia, so that's the problem. Convert your data to numeric type, e.g. `df = df.astype(float)` before you do anything. You shouldn't be holding numeric data in `object` dtype.

Answer (score 1):

We can `concat` , then using `groupby` `fillna` , after split should get what you need

```
s=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],keys=[1,2,3])
s=s.groupby(level=1).apply(lambda x : x.fillna(x.mean()))
df1,df2,df3=[x.reset_index(level=0,drop=True) for _,x in s.groupby(level=0)]
df1
Out[1737]: 
   M1   M2   M3
0   1  1.0  2.0
1   8  5.0  9.0
2   4  2.0  7.0
3   9  6.0  3.0
```